# Distribution of votes by tag

Tags: discussion, statistics

For each tag, I would like to know the distributions of scores of questions and answers. In particular, the mean and median scores.

Comment: [sede](http://data.stackexchange.com) is your friend here.

Comment: The Stack Exchange Data Explorer. Gives you access to our data - you can query it if you know SQL.

Answer (score 1):

To make these kind of searches, please refer to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) where you can query the server.

You simply need some [T-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) knowledge.
All accessible fields and tables are displayed on the right panel when you compose your query.